# Why does computed is being logged two times instead of once?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx, react-dom, mobx-react

- As per the official mobx docs, i understood that when we wrap react event handlers with @action, we should see that mobx derived fns should be batched - computed fns, reaction executor fns, autorun fns.
- If we see that as an example it goes like this:

## Case 1: When react event handler is wrapped with action

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { observable, action, computed, autorun } from "mobx";
import { observer } from "mobx-react";

class Person {
  @observable firstName = "Ramu";
  @observable lastName = "Ratnam";
  @observable initial = "K";

  @computed get fullName() {
    console.log("Computed");
    return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName + " " + this.initial;
  }

  @action
  changeFirstNameAndLastName = () => {
    this.firstName = "Mark";
    this.lastName = "Wayne";
    this.initial = "J";
  };

}

const newPerson = new Person();

// Reaction: log the profile info whenever it changes

// Example React component that observes state
const ProfileView = observer(props => {
  console.log("render ProfileView");

  return (
    <div>
      <p>{props.person.fullName}</p>
      <button onClick={props.person.changeFirstNameAndLastName}>
        Change first name and last name
      </button>
    </div>
  );
});

render(<ProfileView person={newPerson} />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

- When user presses `Change first name and last name` button then due to batching the computed,  ProfileView render fn should be triggered once, which is as expected
- When we remove @action to the `changeFirstNameAndLastName` handler as
  react might still batch the state updates, hence the computed fn should be triggered once and render fn should be called once

> **Instead computed fn is being logged twice**.

- Check `Case 2` snippet for the same.

## Case 2: When react event handler is not wrapped with action

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { observable, action, computed, autorun } from "mobx";
import { observer } from "mobx-react";

class Person {
  @observable firstName = "Ramu";
  @observable lastName = "Ratnam";
  @observable initial = "K";

  @computed get fullName() {
    console.log("Computed");
    return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName + " " + this.initial;
  }

  changeFirstNameAndLastName = () => {
    this.firstName = "Mark";
    this.lastName = "Wayne";
    this.initial = "J";
  };

}

const newPerson = new Person();

// Reaction: log the profile info whenever it changes

// Example React component that observes state
const ProfileView = observer(props => {
  console.log("render ProfileView");

  return (
    <div>
      <p>{props.person.fullName}</p>
      <button onClick={props.person.changeFirstNameAndLastName}>
        Change first name and last name
      </button>
    </div>
  );
});

render(<ProfileView person={newPerson} />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Note:

If react batches the state updates inside changeFirstNameAndLastName, then computed fn should be logged once.

If react does not batches the state updates inside changeFirstNameAndLastName, then computed fn should be logged thrice.

> Why computed fn is being logged twice instead?

Comment: This is really interesting - if you log FirstName, Lastname and middle initial every time fullName is called, you see the first time is the update of firstName but the second time gets both lastName and middle initial updated

Comment: Also pls see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61726239/how-to-determine-when-mobx-computed-variable-is-called), tracking the other variant of this question here.

Comment: Maybe What's happening is as soon as Firstname is updated it calls the computed value then by the time it get's back to the next updates it already updated LastName and middle initial. Make sense?

Comment: It seems it starts batching the updates when it hits the second one. Try adding more values and you'll see it's still only two updates.

Comment: Yes it seems like that. Also, guess by @Antoan Elkov, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61726239/how-to-determine-when-mobx-computed-variable-is-called) is in the similar lines.