# How to determine when mobx computed variable is called.?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx, react-dom, mobx-react

I have been playing with mobx computed, but I am having trouble understanding what is happening with the following code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { observable, computed } from "mobx";
import { observer } from "mobx-react";

@observer
class Counter extends Component {
  @observable count = 0;
  @observable secondCount = 0;

  @computed
  get countString() {
    console.log("countString Computed");
    return `${this.count} ${this.secondCount}`;
  }

  onChangeCount = () => {
    this.count = this.count + 1;
    this.secondCount = this.secondCount + 1;
  };

  render() {
    console.log("render Counter");
    // console.log("count", this.count)
    // console.log("secondCount", this.secondCount)
    return (
      <div>
        <p>Count String: {this.countString}</p>
        <button onClick={this.onChangeCount}>Change count</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<Counter />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

When user presses the change count btn, the output is:

```
countString Computed 
render Counter 
countString Computed
```

- However, when I uncomment the two lines written inside the render fn of Counter component, the output changes

```
 // console.log("count", this.count)
 // console.log("secondCount", this.secondCount)
```

- The output will be:

```
render Counter 
count 1
secondCount 1
countString Computed
```

> ***Why computed fn is being called only once when I dereference the observable variables inside render fn?***

- Mobx 5
- React 0.13.0

Comment: Just a guess.
First case:
1. observer sees there is a change in observable field related to computed 
2. after that it evaluates the value of computed to see if it should render 
3. start rendering
4. get the value of the computed(second console log)

Second case:
1. observer track changes in 2 observable fields.
2. Render is for sure needed, that's why there is no point of calculation of computed property at this point to check if render is needed.
3. Render
4. Evaluating computed property and rendering it in UI

Comment: It explains the above scenario. Any reference backing it would be highly appreciated. TIA.

Comment: Okay lets assume it works as you have guessed. 

Third case: We shall comment this line 

`this.secondCount = this.secondCount + 1;`

so now expected output is:

1. observer sees there is a change in observable field related to computed
2. after that it evaluates the value of computed to see if it should render
3. start rendering
4. get the value of the computed(second console log)

In the actual output:

`4. get the value of the computed(second console log)` log is not coming. So that guess might be not explaining this case. It could be something else.

Comment: Can you provide code sandbox, so I can test and debug it. Thanks

Comment: [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-mobx-todolist-k6s3q?file=/index.js).

Comment: After debugging your code, I can make another guess, that this behavior originally described by you could be because of optimization. What I mean is:
Original case:  when computed is dependent on 2(or n) parameters - first time the observer sees that there could be a change in the computed property(in click event handler), so it should calculate to see if it is a right guess. After seeing the computed actually have changed, there is no point of calculating it again for every parameter, because it can calculate it just one more time when rendering again.

Comment: In your last case - computed is dependent only on one parameter and is already computed once. There is no point to compute it one more time in render method, because it knows that nothing has changed.

Comment: Okay. I do agree with the explanation for now. Any reference backing it would be highly appreciated.